# how to fix the difference in line thickness for a collapsable element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a webpage that uses bootstrap accordion.

There is a line that divides sections. I have included a screenshot.

When the user clicks the 'Read More' the accordion opens.

The problem is that there are lines on the side for each section. When a section opens, the line follows the section, as it should.  However, the thickness of the lines looks off.  I can't figure out how to make this work so it looks the same opened or closed.

[image]
[image]

Code Shared on jsfiddle.net  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8hp2X)

```
jQuery(".readmore").click(function () {
    var thisid = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    var id = thisid.split("-");
    jQuery(".read-" + id[1] + "-text").slideDown();
    jQuery(this).css("display", "none");
});
jQuery(".readclose").click(function () {
    var thisid = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    var id = thisid.split("-");
    jQuery(".read-" + id[1] + "-text").slideUp();
    jQuery("#read-" + id[1]).css("display", "block");
});

<div class="second-section">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="expect-head little-time">Big changes in little time</div>
                <div class="expect-body hasborder-right">TeamUp was developed from over 30 years of coaching the world's top executives. We truly understand what it takes to achieve deep, meaningful life changes, even on a busy schedule.
                        <h3 class="readmore" id="read-1">> Read More</h3>

                    <div class="read-1-text" style="display:none;">Whether you choose to create a healthier lifestyle, deeper relationships, or seek more fulfillment in your career, TeamUp will take you there. You’ll discover your patterns of behavior and consciously choose which ones to keep and which ones to change. You'll experience your life from a new and refreshing perspective.
                            <h3 class="readclose" id="close-1">> Close</h3>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="expect-head results">Results that last a lifetime</div>
                <div class="expect-body hasborder-left">This course is a all about taking action. The specific action to take is determined by you. There are no formulas or a one-size-fits-all. You define your own actions based upon what you want to do differently in your life.
                        <h3 class="readmore" id="read-2">> Read More</h3>

                    <div class="read-2-text" style="display:none;">You are creative and insightful. You probably already know what you want to change. Through your weekly interactions with your teammates, and the course material, you will turn your insights into action to achieve your personal growth goals.
                            <h3 class="readclose" id="close-2">> Close</h3>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="expect-head getsupport">Get Support from your team</div>
                <div class="expect-body hasborder-right">Each week you'll have a 90-minute online conversation with your team members. They will listen, challenge and motivate you. You'll find the strength and courage to overcome any obstacles along the way.
                        <h3 class="readmore" id="read-3">> Read More</h3>

                    <div class="read-3-text" style="display:none;">You will also inspire change in the members of your team. You'll experience first hand how fulfilling it is contributing to others insights and personal growth. Working together is not only more effective...it's more fun.
                            <h3 class="readclose" id="close-3">> Close</h3>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="expect-head ontrack">We'll keep you on track</div>
                <div class="expect-body hasborder-left">A dedicated coach facilitator will guide you, and your team throughout the course. All TeamUp facilitators have been throughly trained and mentored, maintaining the highest standards of confidentiality and integrity.
                        <h3 class="readmore" id="read-4">> Read More</h3>

                    <div class="read-4-text" style="display:none;">Our facilitators know what it takes to make long-lasting change, and will create a safe, inspirational learning environment where you can achieve profound personal growth.
                            <h3 class="readclose" id="close-4">> Close</h3>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.second-section {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666666;
}
.second-section h2 {
    font-size: 56px;
    text-align: center;
}
.second-section .container-fluid {
    padding: 0;
}
.second-section .col-md-6 {
    padding: 0;
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
}
.expect-head {
    color: #000;
    padding: 35px 50px;
    text-align: left;
}
.expect-head h3 {
    line-height: inherit;
}
.expect-body {
    padding: 20px 50px;
    min-height: 210px;
}
.expect-body b {
    font-weight: 600;
}
.readmore, .readclose {
    color: #FF7C00;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: inherit;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.read-1-text, .read-2-text, .read-3-text, .read-4-text {
    margin: 40px 0 0;
}
.hasborder-left {
    border-left: 1px solid #666666;
}
.hasborder-right {
    border-right: 1px solid #666666;
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Share your code on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Looks like a double border

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't that weird that this is happening, because you are putting **two borders on the same place**.

You say to your left div to output a border on the right and to output a border on the left of the most right div. This gives you two borders...

Therefore, you should remove one of them to get a singular border. If you want to have a thicker border, just change the pixel of the border you want to have.

See this for a demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/8hp2X/2/**

```
.hasborder-right {
    border-right: 2px solid #666666;
}
```

As you can see, I have removed one of the borders, which results in a nice looking page.

Comment: Thanks Siyah that really helped fix it.  I appreciate your great response.